# Unable to select image file with tinyMCE's file browser

Tags: content-management-system, tinymce, modx, rich-text-editor

I am using TinyMCE 3.2.4 with my CMS (ModX Evo 1.0.10). I am having an issue with the image/file browser.

The pop up window opens and I can see all the files I have loaded on to the server but I cannot select any to add to the Rich Text area. Permissions are fine, I can even upload an image, but nothing happens when I click one to add it.

I have tried re-installing TinyMCE and the CMS to no avail. Would anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I never had problems with 1010

But for 1011 you can see this fix:

> [#10068] tinyMCE no add images from KCfinder
>   https://raw.github.com/dmi3yy/evolution/master/install/changelog.txt

So try upgrading if you haven't already.